# Can you activate middle name in Salesforce without contacting Salesforce

Tags: contact, fields, customization, setup, standard

When I googled this, found how to [Enable Customizable Person Names using the Middle Name and Suffix fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199209&type=1)

[image]

In Salesforce Customize User Interface found we have this setting below.

[image]

and indeed it enabled Salesforce middle name without having to contact/raise a support case with Salesforce.

Any reason why we have to contact Salesforce to enable these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help topic, as written, was accurate in Spring '15. At some later release, this requirement was removed. You may want to log some feedback with Salesforce to have this topic revised.